# Как исправить: Не удалось создать защищенный канал SSL/TLS?

Tags: c#, winforms

> System.Net.WebException: Запрос был прерван:Не удалось создать защищенный канал SSL/TLS. в System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

```
string html = string.Empty;
string url = "https://google.com";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.KeepAlive = true;

//на всякий пожарный добавил в решений этой ошибки видел подобое
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: у меня ваш код отрабатывает без ошибки. может быть вы сидите за прокси, который ломает https?

Comment: @PashaPash Ошибка плавающая - "время от времени выскакивает". За прокси не сижу.

Comment: Если у исключения нет InnerException, то я бы забил и просто повторял запрос.

Comment: @Monk как определить наличие InnerException?

Comment: @FORTRAN посмотреть в `System.Net.WebException: Запрос был прерван:Не удалось создать защищенный канал SSL/TLS`

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте указать допустимые протоколы

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Мне личнно не помогло.